# Should i be using the uvm_component/object_utils macros

Tags: macros, system-verilog, uvm

I see a lot of articles which talk about whether you should be using field macros.

General guideline is:

```
`uvm_do... macro:
```

Can be used, but try to avoid if you are lazy.

---

```
`uvm_field... macro:
```

Avoid like the plague.

---

Sure, people also tell not to use

```
`uvm_component_param_utils... 
`uvm_object_param_utils...
```

But i cannot seem to find what anyone thinks about the

```
`uvm_component_utils... 
`uvm_object_utils...
```

Should they be avoided? Or they can be used without much issues?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *_utils macros do not introduce any performance penalties. They do save some typing and may reduce typographical errors, but I wish people would learn the code behind the macros before using them. See
[Parameterized Classes, Static Members and the Factory Macros](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2011/02/13/parameterized-classes-static-members-and-the-factory-macros/)

Answer (score 2):

I always use `uvm_field_` and `uvm_object_utils/uvm_component_utils` macros. They provide a lot of nifty features.

One feature I love: The uvm_component will automatically get the variable for you from the uvm_config_db  if you use `uvm_field_*` to register it.

For example:

```
class myclass extends uvm_component;

bit enable;
`uvm_component_utils_begin(myclass)
  `uvm_field_int(bit, UVM_ALL_ON) // UVM_READ_ONLY wouldn't work for this feature
`uvm_component_utils_end

virtual class build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  super.build_phase(phase);
endclass

virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  if (enable) begin
     // blah blah
  end
endtask

endclass
```

To set bit enable, all you have to do in a class that is at a higher hierarchichal level is `uvm_config_db(int)::set(this, "path/to/class", "enable", 1)`

There is no need for any "get" in the class itself. Kinda neat...

Comment: Do you not need to call `super.build_phase(phase)` for this to happen?

Comment: you definitely need to call super.build_phase(); if someone has UVM_READONLY then also it would not autoconfig, it is called only once during build time.

Comment: You guys are right! I am updating the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I taught my first ever UVM course this week (with the Doulos CTO - John Aynsley - sitting in as backup). In his assessment of my performance, he said this about macros, which I'm sure he won't mind me repeating:

> - `uvm_component_utils and friends - a good thing
> - `uvm_do and friends - a bit naughty
> - Field macros - evil

Comment: uvm_component_utils and friends: if u mean the param _*_utils then they cause a lot of issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can work around these two macros.

```
`uvm_component_utils... 
`uvm_object_utils...
```

These two set up the factory.  If you don't use them, you have to write the same few lines of tedious boiler plate code in every one of your uvm_object or uvm_component.

```
uvm_component_param_utils
uvm_object_param_utils
```

is just the same as the previous two, you need to use them when your uvm_object or uvm_component has parameters.  I found having parameters in uvm_object/uvm_componet is handy in some case, but I know some one think it is a bad idea.  But that's another debate.

Personally, I avoid the `uvm_do` macros, I prefer to create and randomize my seq_item with full control, then use `uvm_send (which is just some boiler plate sequencer book keeping)

I took the Doulos training and I remember they said avoid the `uvm_field` macros.  Somehow I just have a feeling that the `uvm_field` macros is kind of complicate, so they simply avoid teaching it because we don't have enough time.

The `uvm_field` macros are VERY useful, specially if you build your own `uvm_comparer`.  Whether or not to implement your own `do_copy, do_print` function is a matter of taste, but the `uvm_comparer` is really useful.  I recommend you always use the `uvm_field` macros